# no idea annotations attached to the jdk в Intelliji idea

Tags: intellij-idea, java

Установил jdk 8 на один из дисков. Указал к нему путь в idea. При открытии проекта получил желтое сообщение:

> no idea annotations attached to the jdk
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: нажать справа на ссылку "Attach annotation" ?

Comment: Возможно вы каталог с jdk повредили, попробуйте заново его установить

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Санаев, да. Пришлось переустановить